# Jitpack Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

Tags: android, android-studio, jitpack

Issue: Receiving error 401 while resolving dependency of a private repo although my subscription status is Active. It used to build and work properly before, but started returning this error recently. I cannot access the Log report on the repo anymore as it asks for credentials now and when I enter Gitlab credentials used for the repo, Jitpack doesn’t recognize that.

Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpErrorStatusCodeException: Could not GET 'https://jitpack.io/com/bongobd/gitlab/mobile-dev/bdroidplayer-v2/2.12.19-rc6/bdroidplayer-v2-2.12.19-rc6.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized